# Access Instance of a Class from a differente Process in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling, marshalbyrefobject

I have a project called "Core" that declares an Interface. And i have a project called "Service" that instantiates a class that implements that interface (it references the "Core" project on it's dependencies).

Both projects run independently, as i can run "Core" (it's an EXE). If i do, i'd like to verify if "Service" is running, and if so, get the instance of a class that is created on the "Service" process and call it's method.

It looks like this (almost).

**On "Core" project**:

```
namespace Core
{
    public interface IController { void Update(long ID, string Value, string Components); }

    public static class Utils
    {
        public static IController Controller;

        internal void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Here, if "Service" is running, then get "Controller" from it
        }
    }
}
```

**On the "Service" project**:

```
namespace Service
{
    internal class ControlMe : Core.IController
    {
        public void Update(long ID, string Value, string Components)
        {
            //Do other things
        }

        internal void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Core.Utils.Controller = new ControlMe();
        }
    }
}
```

It should marshal somehow from one process to another, but i'm unfamiliar with Interop methods that would call that.

Comment: Be sure to change `internal class ControlMe` to `public class ControlMe`. I think you'll have issues with it being `internal` given your use case.

Comment: Process interop is quite limited, intentionally.  You'll have to use the interop mechanisms provided by .NET.  Named pipes, sockets, WCF and a few not worth mentioning because they are way too hard to get right.  Don't do it is the only good advice.

Comment: i may have been too eager to ask; i've been trying to understand this for a while, but i get is something like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example

Comment: the internal/public should no be an issue since the class would be captured by an interface reference; the idea is not to instantiate a new one, but capture one that's already running through differente appdomains; maybe the MarshalByRef is the way to do it - did not get yet hou to prevent multiple instances, but i'm reading about it

Comment: i'll leave this idea alone for now